# How do we customize the grouping from actual array of objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have to create my customized grouping order based on `standardID` in the following array of objects:

Actual Array:

```
var test=[
          {ID: "91",Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1"},
          {ID: "41",Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2"},
          {ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2"},
          {ID: "2",Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2"},
          {ID: "2",Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3"},
          {ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201"}
         ]
```

Expected Result: I Simply want to group the `standardID`'s like `1,3,2,2,2,201`

```
[
    {ID: "91",Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1"},
    {ID: "2",Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3"},
    {ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201"},
    {ID: "41",Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2"},
    {ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2"},
    {ID: "2",Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2"}
]
```

Kindly help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: How do you want to sort it? Based on what?

Comment: What is the context in which you want to sort the elements? As the question is tagged with angularjs you could look into [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: @ulferts yes am l used orderby but it not's work.here i have to sort based on standard id ,can you please look in to the expected result.

Comment: @mrgeek based on standardID

Comment: The expected result isn't sorted in anyway, perhaps you switched the expected output with the actual array in your question.

Comment: @MrGeek now i updated my question kindly look in to the expected result.

Comment: How is `1 3 2 2 2 201` grouped? I don't see a logic behind it!

Comment: @MrGeek based on this i have to show the name...ng-repeat

Comment: Can you just tell me how is `1 3 2 2 2 201` sorted? Maybe you want `1 2 2 2 201 3` instead?

Comment: Anyways, I have a workaround in my answer if you want to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pure javascript and this will "sort" it your way, define your sort order in groupOrder variable:

```
var groupOrder = [1,3,201,2];
var testSorted = test.sort((a, b) => groupOrder.indexOf(parseInt(a.standardID))-groupOrder.indexOf(parseInt(b.standardID)));
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pLe44x1x/1/

Comment: :here am not looking for ascending order ... based on the standard id only i need to grouping array of objects.

Comment: ok, now it's using standardID, but can you update your question with real expected result?

Comment: expected result [{ID: "91",Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1"},
{ID: "2",Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3"},
{ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201"}
{ID: "41",Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2"}
{ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2"}
{ID: "2",Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2"}
}
],here order like first 1,second 3,third 2,fourth 2,fifth 2,sixth 201

Comment: @pegala why dont it works with following code change kindly reply me:var groupOrder = [1,3,2,201];
var testSorted = test.sort(function (a, b) {groupOrder.indexOf(parseInt(a.standardID))-groupOrder.indexOf(parseInt(b.standardID))});

Comment: I updated the answer, it's all about that groupingOrder - if you have 1,3,2,201 it will sort them in that order - I just noticed you wanted 201 before 2 so I just changed it to 1,3,201,2

Comment: here i need to avoid lambda function (instead => i have use function(a,b)) in sorting but its not working.the reason to avoid => it fail all the karma test case...

Comment: You're missing return, if you use normal function you need to return everything in brackets

Answer (score 1):

You can try this prototype custom sorting by attributes objects :

```
var test=[{ID: "91",Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1"},
{ID: "41",Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2"},
{ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2"},
{ID: "2",Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2"},
{ID: "2",Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3"},
{ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201"}
];
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXNpMZ?editors=1112

@Sathish

UPDATED in ordered by indexes array reference here :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLoZOX?editors=1112

Comment: am not looking for ascending order.i have to grouping like 1,3,2,2,2,201 as well

Comment: @Sathish look at the second link about sorting by array indexes reference, regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `sort` function with your own criteria (map):

```js
var test = [
  {ID: "91",Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1"},
  {ID: "41",Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2"},
  {ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2"},
  {ID: "2",Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2"},
  {ID: "2",Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3"},
  {ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201"}
];
var myMap = {
            "1": 0,
            "3": 1,
            "2": 2
          };

test.sort((a, b) => myMap[a.standardID[0]] - myMap[b.standardID[0]]);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [{
    ID: "91",
    Name: "sgtue",
    standardID: "1"
  },
  {
    ID: "41",
    Name: "asdfasdf",
    standardID: "2"
  },
  {
    ID: "5",
    Name: "credd",
    standardID: "2"
  },
  {
    ID: "2",
    Name: "dddawer",
    standardID: "2"
  },
  {
    ID: "2",
    Name: "dsfadf",
    standardID: "3"
  },
  {
    ID: "275",
    Name: "xcvcvc",
    standardID: "201"
  }
];


// parseInt used because of your input datatype
var sortOrder = [1,3,2,201];
var out = test.sort(function(a, b) {
    return sortOrder.indexOf(parseInt(a.standardID)) - sortOrder.indexOf(parseInt(b.standardID));
});

//sorted
console.log(out)
```