# use sorting function with out lambda function using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lambda

Following solution will be worked well when am using lambda function.due to some karma test case failure i have to avoid lambda function in sorting.i don't know how to overcome this issue.now the following code is not working for me

```
var test=[{ID: "91",Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1"},
{ID: "41",Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2"},
{ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2"},
{ID: "2",Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2"},
{ID: "2",Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3"},
{ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201"}
];


var groupOrder = [1,3,2,201];
var testSorted = test.sort(function (a, b) {groupOrder.indexOf(parseInt(a.standardID))-groupOrder.indexOf(parseInt(b.standardID))}); 


console.log(testSorted);
```

The same concept will be working on the following link:
[fiddle working link](https://jsfiddle.net/pLe44x1x/1/)

And following link is my actual question:
[How do we customize the grouping from actual array of objects in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389698/how-do-we-customize-the-grouping-from-actual-array-of-objects-in-angularjs/46389734)

Comment: *"due to some karma test case failure"* – I don't see how that's connected to a sort callback. You should ask a concrete question about *that* issue. http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var testSorted = test.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.standardID)-parseInt(b.standardID));`?

Comment: "due to some karma test case failure i have to avoid lambda function in sorting".  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Instead of asking how to solve your *problem* (karma test failure), you are asking about your *potential solution* (avoiding lambda), which may or may not be correct or useful.  You might consider actually asking about the karma error, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of sort calculation.

```js
var test = [{ ID: "91", Name: "sgtue", standardID: "1" }, { ID: "41", Name: "asdfasdf", standardID: "2" }, { ID: "5", Name: "credd", standardID: "2" }, { ID: "2", Name: "dddawer", standardID: "2" }, { ID: "2", Name: "dsfadf", standardID: "3" }, { ID: "275", Name: "xcvcvc", standardID: "201" }],
    groupOrder = [1, 3, 2, 201];

test.sort(function(a, b) {
    return groupOrder.indexOf(+a.standardID) - groupOrder.indexOf(+b.standardID);
    // ^^^
});

console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```